# How to remove new line or line breaks while parsing data from an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, newline, line-breaks

I am trying to parse a csv file to insert the csv contents into my Database. After the data is parsed the array looks like

```
Array
(
    [AirportCode
] => GKA

)
```

and i would like to extract the AirportCode GKA and insert it. Everything looks fine but the key and Value in the above array having line breaks.

Sample code:

```
foreach($data['csvData'] as $field)
{
    print_r($field);
    $AirportCode =  str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $field['AirportCode']);

    echo $AirportCode ;     
}
```

But the AirportCode is always returning empty. I just want to get-rid of those line breaks. Can someone help me...?

Comment: AirportCode is returning empty because the key reference has a line break in them?

Comment: Yes @ZanderRootman and the value is also having a line break.

Answer (score 2):

**Untested**
I'm not sure about `str_replace()` capabilities on recognizing newline characters by using the escape reference, but it's worth a shot.

However your airport code is returning nothing, because the actual key seems to have a \n (new line character) in.

```
function fixArrayKey(&$arr)
{
    $arr=array_combine(array_map(function($str){
        return str_replace("\n ","",$str);
    },array_keys($arr)),array_values($arr));

    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(is_array($val)) fixArrayKey($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

For your array values however you could just use:

```
function fixArrayValue($arr)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach($arr AS $key => $value){
        $return[$key] = rtrim($value, "\n");
    }
    return $return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no array key called `'AirportCode'` the actual key has a line break in it.
I would create a clean array by looping through the key value pairs, and adding them to a new array:

```
$clean=array();
foreach($data['csvData'] as $key => $value){
    $ckey = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $key);
    $cvalue = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $value);
    $clean[$ckey]=$cvalue;
}

var_dump($clean);
```

Comment: I tried creating new array but this results the same as above. :-(

Comment: @Ramaraju.d please see my edit, PHP_EOL may not be a good solution.

Comment: `no luck` what exactly do you mean? Are you still getting the line breaks in the array, or are you getting empty values

Comment: Actually i tried the same thing before posting it into stackoverflow. but not with the idea of creating a new array as you suggested.

Comment: Well your code results in empty values because it attempts to access a non existant array key. My code does not - there is no way the values in `$clean` array can be empty in my code if they are present in `$data['csvData']`. Unless you can recreate this problem somewhere i can test it (codepad etc) i can only guess whats wrong